Movie featuring a man with red sombrero walking through firing field
I found this question from my Twitter timeline (Korean).
I feel like seen this movie but can't remember any detail.
No help with Google image search.
This tweet link contains a short clip: https://twitter.com/Ooorial/status/491434368175337472


This is from Lucky Luke and the Daltons from 2004. IIRC it's a magic red sombrero that makes the wearer invulnerable. You can see the scene here (the exact moment is around 1:35):



